# Alamofire server trust policy does not work for me

Tags: ios, alamofire, nsurlsession

I would like to override the security on my server because we are testing something in the future. I create a global Alamofire manager and set the server trust policy but it does not work. I change my domain to blah but I double check to make sure that it is the same.

```
class HTTPManager: Alamofire.Manager {
    static let sharedManager: HTTPManager = {

        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "qa.blah.me": .DisableEvaluation
        ]
        let serverTrustPolicyManger = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)

        let configuration = Timberjack.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        let manager = HTTPManager(configuration: configuration, serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManger)

        return manager
    }()
}
```

This is how I use it.

```
HTTPManager.sharedManager.request(request).responseJSON(completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Error: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “qa.blah.me” which could put your confidential information at risk.
Suggestion: Would you like to connect to the server anyway?
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

PS: Alamofire 3.0

Answer (score 0):

try to instantiate manager as Alamofire.manager instead HTTPManager

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely being hit by [ATS](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#app-transport-security) so the `ServerTrustPolicy` is probably not even getting called. I'd recommend reading through the entire [Security](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#security) section of the Alamofire README to make sure you have things configured correctly.

A quick way to tell if you're `ServerTrustPolicy` is being called is to drop a breakpoint in the `serverTrustPolicyForHost()` method and see if it gets called.

There's also no reason anymore to not cut valid certificates. You can create free certificates at [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org).